# How can I check if a text field value has the correct format?

Tags: javascript, forms

i have a textfield, which is there for a Date in YYYY-MM-DD format. What I want to do is to check for the correctness of the date. 
My concept would be:

```
deadline = document.getElementById("Deadline").value;
if (deadline[0] == "0" || 
    deadline[0] == "1" ||
    deadline[0] == "2" || 
    deadline[0] == "3" || 
    deadline[0] == "4" || 
    deadline[0] == "5" ||
    deadline[0] == "6" ||
    deadline[0] == "7" ||
    deadline[0] == "8" ||
    deadline[0] == "9" ){
    if(deadline[1] == "0" || ...){
        if(deadline[2] == "0" || ...){
            ...

            }else{alert("Wrong Format!")}
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: It's `document`, lowercase !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using a `RegExp` will give you a rough idea about the correctness of format, it will not check the validity of the values. A better approach may be something like this.

```js
function inRange (val, min, max) {
    return val >= min && val <= max;
}

var deadLine = document.getElementById('deadline'),
    out = document.getElementById('out');

deadLine.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var text = e.target.value,
        valid,
        parts,
        year,
        month,
        day,
        result;

    if ((/^\d{1,4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/).test(text)) {
        parts = text.split('-');
        year = parts[0];
        month = parts[1];
        day = parts[2],
        valid = inRange (year, 0, 9999) &&
                inRange (month, 1, 12) &&
                inRange (day, 0, 31) &&
                day == new Date(year, month - 1, day).getDate();
    }

    if (valid) {
        result = 'Correct Format and date!';
    } else {
        result = 'Wrong Format or date!';
    }
    
    out.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result + '\n'));
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="deadline" type="text"></input>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Regex:

```js
// yyyy-mm-dd
var re = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;

alert(re.test("2001-11-02"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expression. Check the code at https://regex101.com/r/iO0pY2/1. Here how you can use it:

```
var str = '2015-02-05'
var re = /^(\d{4})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})$/
var valid = re.test(str);
```

Comment: No need for parenthesis or for escaping the hyphens. Unless, of course, you want to use the year, month and day values later.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg true